# Where am I getting Segmentation Fault in this code?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
    class Solution
{
    public:
    //Heapify function to maintain heap property.
    void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i)  
    {
      if(i<=0)return;
      int parent = i-1/2;
      if(arr[i] < arr[parent]){
          int temp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[parent];
          arr[parent] = temp;
      }
      heapify(arr,n,parent);
      
    }

    public:
    //Function to build a Heap from array.
    void buildHeap(int arr[], int n)  
    { 
        for(int i=n/2-1;i>=0;i--){
            heapify(arr,n,i);
        }
        
    }

    
    public:
    //Function to sort an array using Heap Sort.
    void heapSort(int arr[], int n)
    {
        buildHeap(arr,n);
        
    }
};
```

Comment: *Where am I getting Segmentation Fault in this code?* -- Run the code in a debugger until it crashes.  Then look at the call stack.  BTW, there is no program -- where is the `main` function with the data that is being used?

Comment: `i-1/2`: Given operator precedence and the way integer division works, I am pretty sure this is not what you meant to write.

Comment: You'd better debug with the input data, seems it's like a leetcode problem, when your code fails, you can see the input data on the site.

Comment: `1/2` is zero because of integer division, so `i-1/2` is `i-0` which is likely not what you want.